# org.eclipse.core.resources in tycho build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho

I have the maven build that generated by xtext platform. My application uses the org.eclipse.core.resource bundle. The build by eclipse IDE is completed with success. The build by maven failed because of org.eclipse.core.resources is not found by maven build. I understand that this bundle shall  be added to target platform definition, there a several to do it. I can add reference to current eclipse installation, but this is not good way. I cannot find location of p2 repository where org.eclipse.core.resources is located.

Could you please c clarify the way that should be used for searching unresolved bundle in tycho build?

```html
<target name="com.psl.atom.target" sequenceNumber="1">         
<locations>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.core.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.platform.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.pde.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.draw2d.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.xpand" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.xtend" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.xtend.typesystem.emf" version="0.0.0"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201606221000/"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launcher.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/mwe/updates/releases/2.9.0/"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.xtext.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/releases/2.12.0/"/>
</location>
</locations>
</target>
```

Comment: The problem was resolved. The root cause of issue was : the generated target file contains reference to old repository. When I changed to latest repository the issue was resolved. The following application will help me to resolve this issue : https://github.com/ifedorenko/p2-browser. This application allows to investigate remote repositories

Comment: Issue can be closed

Comment: main problem is that the eclipse download servers are stable like a jenga tower after 20 mins of gameplay. it should work with that repos as well